# bean reference again reference to another bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

```
@Autowired
private Map<Integer, String> departments;
```

**My spring config file**

```
 <bean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />

 <util:map id="myMap" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap" key-type="java.lang.Integer" value-type="java.lang.String"/>

 <bean id="departments" ....="myMap"> </bean>
```

whenever date is needed using @Autowired it works fine

Similarly,

How i will configure departments with ref "myMap" without property tag?

Comment: What is the type of bean with id="departments"? Are you actually trying to populate the `private Map<Integer, String> departments;` in Spring for use within other bean?

Comment: Yes, i want to populate data. '@Autowired private Date date;' wherever i want to use date it is injected by spring container.

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In you Spring xml configuration you need:

```
<util:map id="myMap" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap" key-type="java.lang.Integer" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="1" value="Value1"/>
        <entry key="2" value="Value2"/>
        <entry key="3" value="Value3"/>
</util:map>
```

Then you can inject the map using `@Resource(name="myMap")` instead of `@Autowired` into any Spring bean that needs the map